# Qt: Static linking of libraries

Tags: qt, static, linker

I'm developing a Qt application in windows. I have created a lib file in visual studio. I have included the header file containing function prototypes in my Qt App and also added lib file in .pro file as follows

```
        win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../Lib/ -lCpLib
        INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Lib
        DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Lib
        win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../Lib/CpLib.lib
```

I called the functions from my Qt app. It shows compile error as "undefined reference"
Please help me.

Regards....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of your LIBS is passing linker arguments in gcc format (i.e. using `-L` to specify the directory and `-l` to specify the library name).

As you have created your lib file in Visual Studio, you'll need to specify the full library name

e.g.

```
win32: LIBS += yourlibrary.lib
```

alternatively, recompile the libraries using MinGW